# Invalidate Token jwt logout - Nodejs and Keycloack

Tags: node.js, keycloak

How do I invalidate a jwt token in Nodejs with keycloak when logging out of an application?

So far no viable documentation

Comment: The advantage of JWTs is that they contain additional information and can be locally verified without contacting the authorization server. The disadvantage is that they cannot be invalidated. If your application uses sessions, you can logout the application session and at the same time logout on Keycloak. The he/she needs to go through an explicit login again. If your application has the role of a resource server, then you would need to blacklist the JWT or check the session with Keycloak for each request.

Comment: Excellent!
I will do it and come back with the result.

Comment: All done! Excellent.
All very well! I used keycloack's logout endpoint
http://{domain-name}/auth/realms/{realm-name}/protocol/openid-connect/logout

Thanks.